# Is the bijectivity of a function equivalent to monotony and continuity?

Tags: functions, continuity

My high-school math professor told us that in order for a function $ f $ to have a reverse it must be monotonic and continuous, but I always thought that necessary and sufficient condition for a function to be invertible is bijectivity.

Are these conditions equivalent? Or is the first stronger than the second?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a counterexample for the implication "bijective implies continuous and monotonic", consider the bijection $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ -x & x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
This is neither monotonic nor continuous, but is a bijection.

However, the implication "continuous and monotonic implies bijective" is true, as mookid points out.

So monotonicity and continuity together are strictly stronger than being bijective.

Answer (score 1):

The precise statement is: if $f:[a,c]\to [c,d]$ is continuous, then
it is bijective (it means: has a reverse) if and only if it is monotonic.